# New Duplicate Feature

Tags: feature-request, editing, exact-duplicates

It's been pointed out to me (thanks Cai) that [Gold tag-badge holders and moderators can now edit duplicate links](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/291824/gold-tag-badge-holders-and-moderators-can-now-edit-duplicate-links)

This allows us to mark multiple duplicates in an easier and more organized fashion.

I'll be perfectly honest and say I'm not going to search out multiple duplicates most of the time. I also wouldn't expect any of you to do that. If you happen to know one you want to add though feel free.

If people vote to close for different duplicate questions then they should all show up.

Comment: Worth noting that Scott is the only active user with a gold tag badge so most users can't do much with this... unless they ping a mod (or Scott for PS or AI questions). Still a useful feature though, I can think of a few regular questions that could use this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you know of a Q&A that could qualify as a duplicate and the question has already been closed or the question is of age feel free to either flag for  moderator attention:

[image]

or bring it up in the [Ink Spot](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1240/the-ink-spot).